# Should I decouple MVC from WebAPI 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-web-api

I have a situation where I'm having difficulty in choosing the best approach.

I need to create/design 3 systems :
System A : From which one is supposed to be api/MVC UI web application to handle business data.

System B : Consuming and sending data to System A

(Possibly) System C : Centralized login/token server

So at the moment I have been thinking of decoupling MVC from webAPI and have them within same domain i.e. http://server.com/UI and http://server.com/api

System B is already finished so here I just need to investigate in logic for authorization and consumption

System C : for APIs I was thinking of using JWT however for centralized user login I have no idea how to handle login on this system so it would be authenticated on system A

Any guidelines to approach would be much appreciated!

Thanks
Raf

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your question is, but it appears to be a question like "should my application be architecture x or y?".  These kind of questions aren't a good fit for this format, because they don't draw on any concrete facts, and instead rely upon opinions which could vary based on your problem domain.  What is necessary in one scenario may be impossible in another, and more than one answer could be right.

Comment: Agreed with above comment. (But in reality yes decouple, have in two separate projects.... this is how the system I'm working on now works, maybe think about api.server.com and www.server.com)

Comment: Thanks for your comments. In did as @Claies mentioned I did not really specified problem which could be solved here but opened a spot for discussion. I think that I will go with seperation and have one for api.server.com and one server.com/. Thanks!